# Comparing two sets of data, one is rounded to 7 decimals places and the other to 8

Tags: vba, excel

I am comparing two sets of data. I need help with a part of an `IF` statement. it looks something like this:

```
Sheets("sheet1").Select

Dim cell As Range

For Each cell In Range("A3:A200")
    If [condition1] And [condition2] And [condition3] And _
          Worksheets("name1").Range("BE" & cell.row - 1) = Worksheets("name2").Range
          ("X" & cell.Row) Then
        [do code]
    Else
        [do something]
    End If
    ...
Next
```

There are about 50 conditions. However `"name1"` sheet has 8 decimals places in `BE` and `"name2"` sheet has 7 in `X`. So it's failing. How can I round or fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of:

```
IF Round(WorkSheets("name").Range("BE" & cell.row - 1) , 7)
```

can be used to round of the cells with 8 decimal places down to seven. If perhaps you still don't match due to precision, you can round each of the cases down to 6 (or 5, or 4...) decimal places. This may possibly reduce precision, but will increase the number of matches.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are testing for equity between two floating point numbers, you can kill two birds with one stone and use an epsilon comparison instead of testing equality:

```
Const Epsilon As Double = 0.00000001

'...

Dim cell As Range
Dim value1 As Double, value2 As Double
For Each cell In Range("A3:A200")
    value1 = Worksheets("name1").Range("BE" & cell.Row - 1)
    value2 = Worksheets("name2").Range("X" & cell.Row)
    If condition1 And condition2 And condition3 And _
    (value1 - value2 < Epsilon) Then
        'do code
    Else
        'do something
    End If
```